# Linq to XML query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm loading from a xml some information about city's points of interest, and my xml structure looks like this:

```
<InterestPoint>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Residencia PAC</name>        
        <images>
            <image>C:\Pictures\Alien Places in The World\20090625-alien11.jpg</image>
            <image>C:\Alien Places in The World\20090625-alien13.jpg</image>
        </images>
        <desc>blah blah blah blah</desc>
        <Latitude>40.286458</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-7.511921</Longitude>
    </InterestPoint>
```

I'm having trouble to retrieve the images information, I'm only able to get one image, but in these example there are two. The Linq query that i am using is:

```
CityPins = (from c in PointofInterest.Descendants("InterestPoint")
                       select new InterestPoint
                       {
                           // = c.Attribute("Latitude").Value,
                           //longitude = c.Attribute("Longitude").Value,

                           Name = c.Element("nome").Value,
                           LatLong = new VELatLong(double.Parse(c.Element("Latitude").Value), double.Parse(c.Element("Longitude").Value)),
                           Desc = c.Element("descricao").Value,
                           Images = (from img in c.Descendants("imagens")
                           select new POIimage
                           {

                               image = new Uri(img.Element("imagem").Value),


                           }).ToList<POIimage>(),                       




                       }).ToList<InterestPoint>();
```

Images is a `List<POIimages>` where POIimage is a class with a Uri field.

Could someone help me fix this query?

Comment: Can there be multiple `<images>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `c.Descendants("images")`, you are iterating over all of the `<images>` elements, and getting their first `<image>` element by calling `img.Element("imagem")`.

Since there is only one `<images>` (which happens to contain multiple `<image>` elements), you're only getting one image.
The other `<image>` elements inside of `<images>` are ignored, since you don't do anything with them.

You need to call `c.Descendants("image")` in the inner query to get all of the `<image>` elements.

For example:

```
Images = (from img in c.Descendants("image")
          select new POIimage { image = new Uri(img.Value) }
         ).ToList(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ( couldn;t test, don't have VS editor as of now).

```
...
Images = (from img in c.Descendants("image")).SelectMany( new POIimage 
                           { 
                                image = new Uri(img.Element("imagem").Value)
                           }).ToList<POIimage>(),
```